# How to Change Default Port used by MySQL via MySQL Admin?

Tags: mysql

How to Change Default Port used by MySQL via MySQL Admin? I want to use other ports, such as 3307, instead of the default one, 3306.

How to do it via MySQL Administrator GUI program? If it's not possible then it will be helpful if have the instruction for the console program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default port for MySQL is 3306. If you need to change it, you can add the following line

```
port = 3307
```

to your /etc/my.cnf config file. After changing this you'll need to restart you mysql server to pickup the change

```
service mysqld restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change it via MySQL Admin.  [Here's a post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-default-mysql-port-under-linuxunix/) that explains how to do it via conf file in *nix.